# Glossaries-extra: only short style for ignored/common abbreviations

Tags: acronyms, glossaries-extra

How can I set in `glossaries-extra` the `short-nolong` style for my common abbreviations that are ignored when printing the list of abbreviations? `\setabbreviationstyle[common]{short-nolong}` or only `short` does not seem to work here. My idea is that I can decide later on, if I want to include them in the list by deleting the `type=common` option. Further, the definition of the short plural is ignored here in the MWE and a "s" is appended instead. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

MWE (xelatex):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[abbreviations,symbols,nonumberlist,nogroupskip,automake]{glossaries-extra}

\newignoredglossary{common}
\setabbreviationstyle[common]{short-nolong}

% Abbreviations
\newabbreviation{abb:dft}{DFT}{discrete Fourier transfom}

\newabbreviation[
    type=common,
    description={Piece(s)},
    plural={pc.},
    \glslongpluralkey={pieces},
]{abb:piece}{pc.}{piece}

\makeglossaries[abbreviations]

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=abbreviations]

\chapter{Test}

\Gls{abb:dft} and second use \gls{abb:dft}

1 \gls{abb:piece}, second use 1 \gls{abb:piece}\\
10 \glspl{abb:piece}, second use 10 \glspl{abb:piece}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation states

> ```latex
> \setabbreviationstyle[〈category〉]{〈style-name〉}
> ```

the optional argument of `\setabbreviationstyle` takes a *category*, not a *type*. Saying `category=common` in addition to `type=common` in the `\newabbreviation` options does what you want.

Comment: I've tried `\setabbreviationstyle[category=common,type=common]{short-nolong}` but I still get the same output and the plural key is also ignores.

Comment: Ok, `shortplural` key fixed this plural issue. But as mentioned, setting the style wasn't crowned by success.

Comment: @DanielStich You misunderstand. You need to add the glossary _entry_ to the category, i.e. add `category=common` to the options of `\newabbreviation` (next to `type=common`).

Comment: Ah sorry, I don't know why I didn't got that first go. Thanks!